# <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView not showing in lookup list when typing in my layout .xml file

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

I added this statement to my build.gradle at the app module level.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
```

When I switch over to my activity_main.xml file and start typing
"`<android`", I expect to see "`<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView`" as one of the options in the list displayed but I don't.

Actually, I do see it listed in one layout file when I type, but when I switch to the another layout file and try to start typing "<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" doesn't display.

I tried "Sync Project with Gradle Files" as well as "Rebuild Project", but neither seems to have an effect.

I actually closed the project and retried it in a new separate project and getting the same results.

Is this a bug? Or am I missing a step?

Comment: Oh, I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Odd, I tried this with the RecyclerView as well as CardView.

Neither the RecyclerView or the CardView tag shows up in the list until I type as far as `<android.support.v`.